# Obtain a vector of name concatenated with id from a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, list, apply

I have a list of data frames like the following:

```
mylist=list()
mylist[['name1']]=data.frame(marker=LETTERS[1:3],values=1:3)
mylist[['name2']]=data.frame(marker=LETTERS[1:2],values=11:12)
```

that looks like:

```
mylist
$name1
  marker values
1      A      1
2      B      2
3      C      3

$name2
  marker values
1      A     11
2      B     12
```

All I want to do is to obtain a vector using the list names and the marker elements, so that it looks like:

```
> markers_in_names
[1] "A@name1" "B@name1" "C@name1" "A@name2" "B@name2"
```

How should I obtain this with the `apply` family of functions and `paste`, `collapse` in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `lapply` (edit: changed from `sapply` to `lapply` where by default it does not have the name attribute and therefore we can further shorten the code by a bit):

```r
unlist(lapply(names(mylist), \(x) paste0(mylist[[x]][["marker"]], "@", x)))
[1] "A@name1" "B@name1" "C@name1" "A@name2" "B@name2"
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
mapply(\(x, y) paste(x$marker, y, sep = "@"), mylist, names(mylist)) |>
  unlist() |>
  unname()
#> [1] "A@name1" "B@name1" "C@name1" "A@name2" "B@name2"
```

For readability, I formated this as three lines.